# Starting a .cmd file programmatically in CF

Tags: c#, process, batch-file

This works fine:

```
_proc = new Process();
_proc.StartInfo.FileName = "\\Folder\\File.exe";
//Globals._proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k";
_proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
_proc.Start();
_proc.WaitForExit();
```

This does not:

```
_proc = new Process();
_proc.StartInfo.FileName = "\\Folder\\File.cmd";
_proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k";
_proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //tried "true" too
_proc.Start();
_proc.WaitForExit();
```

I get a Win32Exception with no more info. How can I run the .cmd file on my smart device?

Comment: You've changed the FileName from .exe to .cmd in those two examples.  Is that the problem?

Comment: No that was the question, how I can open the .cmd file.

Comment: Ah I'm with you, I thought you were having problems passing the /k argument (as in one example you had it commented out, in the other you didn't).

Comment: Does *your version* of your smart device have a command processor? To my (admittedly limited) knowledge, not all of them do. On regular windows, the location of cmd.exe is available as the %COMSPEC% environment variable - do you have one of those?

Comment: No as I cant find any cmd.exe I dont think it has one.

Comment: @mdc - Try searching for `cmd.*`. Or (I'm hesitant to suggest) maybe `command.*`. Who knows. What kind of device is it?

Answer (score 1):

try using `CMD.EXE` as your "start" program:

```
_proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
_proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \\Folder\\File.cmd /k";
```

Comment: Then I get "The system cannot find the file specified."...any ideas? Tried removing /c and /k.

Comment: I would assume `cmd.exe` is in your envorinment path, so it may not be able to find the CMD file.  Try something simple like `/c dir` instead of your CMD file.

Comment: Still cant find the file. Where is cmd.exe located? Cand find it on the device.

Comment: What type of device and what version of CE?  My answer was based on this MSDN article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms879823.aspx

Comment: Would providing the path to CMD.exe help?  _proc.StartInfo.FileName = "%windir%\\system32\\cmd.exe";

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @D Stanley that you should be using CMD.exe, and passing your file.cmd as a "command" to it via the arguments.

But this article (while specifically talking about .bat files) implies that you may need to set up some registry entries before you can use CMD.EXE.  This may apply also to .CMD files?

[How to run a .bat file on a Windows CE Handheld PC using cmd.exe](http://www.hpcfactor.com/support/cesd/s/0126.asp)

Comment: That article seems to assume there is a cmd.exe in the Windows folder on the device, but I cant see any?

Comment: Only other vaguely relevant thing I could find on the 'net about this situation was along the lines of "contact your device vendor and ask them to provide a version of the OS with CMD included"...  Guess it couldn't hurt to ask... but I don't think you should hold your breath while you wait for it to happen :-(